Principles and Techniques in Combinatorics Adapted Question 14 part (iv) and (v)
Before, I say the question, let me clarify notation. $P_r^n$ is the permutation formula $\dfrac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. Now for the question.

Given that $P_r^{n+1} = P_r^n + rP_{r-1}^n$, prove that $P^{n+1}_r = r! + r(P^n_{r-1} + P^{n-1}_{r-1} + \dots + P^{r}_{r-1})$

I know that I will have to deconstruct the equation given in the first statement, but I do  not know how. Please give me a hint.

I have posted 3 questions and provided answers to all of them! I deserve a raise!

I could be mistaken; this comment is just off the top of my head.  It appears to me (perhaps wrongly) that if you divide both sides of the equation by $~r!,~$ you end up with the hockey stick identity.

Looking at problem 14, yes you do need (iv) to solve it. But remember this: $P_r^n$ can be deconstructed. Think of it as a nested problem with two cases: the permutation contains "1" or it does not. If it contains one, then the permutation is equal to $rP^{n-1}_{r-1}$. If it does not contain one, then the permutation is simply $P^{n-1}_r$. You add these two to get $P^{n-1}_{r-1} + P^{n-1}_r$. Now, if we apply this to the problem:
$$ rP^n_{r-1} + rP^{n-1}_{r-1} + P^{n-1}_r$$ Now we deconstruct the $P^{n-1}_r$. We do it in the same way as we did with $P^n_r$: $P^{n-1}_r = rP^{n-2}_{r-1} + P^{n-2}_r$. So now we are at: $$rP^n_{r-1} + rP^{n-1}_{r-1} + rP^{n-2}_{r-1} + P^{n-2}_r$$ If we keep deconstructing we will arrive at this:
$$rP^n_{r-1} + rP^{n-1}_{r-1} + rP^{n-2}_{r-1} +  \dots + P^{r+1}_r$$ Using the same process, we know that $P^{r+1}_r = rP^{r}_{r-1} + P^r_r$. Hence, our final equation will be:
$$rP^n_{r-1} + rP^{n-1}_{r-1} + rP^{n-2}_{r-1} + \dots + rP^{r}_{r-1} + P^r_r$$ Which finally equals to $$r! + r(P^n_{r-1} + P^{n-1}_{r-1} + P^{n-2}_{r-1} + \dots + P^{r}_{r-1}) \blacksquare$$
